# Using the_title() and fetching the parent page's title and slug to construct breadcrumbs

Tags: breadcrumb

I'm trying to construct a breadcrumb trail where some of the paths consist of parent/child custom post types.

For example:

```
else if ( is_singular( 'resort' ) ) {
    global $post;
    $post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);
    $parent_title = $post_data->post_title;
    $parent_slug = $post_data->post_name;

    echo '<li><a href="/destinations/" title="' . __('Destinations', 'bookyourtravel') . '">' . __('Destinations', 'bookyourtravel') . '</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="/destinations/' . $parent_slug . '/" title="' . $parent_title . ' Villas">' . $parent_title . '</li>';
}
```

Whilst this outputs exactly what I'm after, for example:

```
Destinations > $parent_title
```

When I try to get the current page's title for the last path in the breadcrumb simply with:

```
echo "<li>";
echo the_title();
echo "</li>";
```

It ends up duplicating the second destination > $parent_title path above...

I attach a screenshot of the source code to illustrate this problem.

It seems by the usage of `the_title()`, it seems to wrap any mention of the current page title (Playa Blanca) in a link which links back to the parent page (Lanzarote) which hopefully can be seen in the image.

[image]

Why can't the above just echo the current page title (`the_title()`) at the end of the breadcrumb trail properly?

I just want 'Playa Blanca' to be at the end of the breadcrumb trail not linked and not interfering with anything else on the page.

Comment: You're missing the closing `</a>` in your first code block, the browser will try to fix this by adding markup. Also note that `the_title()` echoes its value by default, so `echo the_title()` is redundant.

Comment: Oh for god sake :D Thanks @Milo - that was the problem! Hah

Comment: also: [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) echoes the title, by default. Use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) instead.